# How to solve the error: WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management

```
wazir@wazir:~$ sudo software-properties-gtk
[sudo] password for wazir: 

(process:15506): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Cannot set locale: unsupported locale setting
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 104, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 89, in __init__
    SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 585, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 87, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException("Error: could not find a "
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template
```

Answer (score 8):

Changing the permissions might work:

```
sudo chmod -R 0644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

*UPDATE: I previously set the mode to 0420, which worked in my case, but per comments and further testing it seems that 0644 is correct.*

Comment: The proper permission would be 644 on those files.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I tried 644 and it did not work. The files in that directory that were not throwing errors already had 0420 mode, so I applied that to the remaining files to get it to work.

Comment: Indeed i have a source, a clean install on a VM where I just looked at the directory and each file has `-rw-r--r--. 1 root root` which is in fact 644. Beside that giving the owner only read rights prevents later changes on this file greatly and I'm not really sure why you think the group needs write access but the owner not this is what your given permissions imply is `-r---w----. 1 root root` and thats plain wrong. See as well https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: Directories should be executable or else you can't get listings of them. You want `sudo find -type d /etc/apt/sources.list.d -print0 |sudo xargs -0 chmod 0755 && sudo find -type f /etc/apt/sources.list.d -print0 |sudo xargs -0 chmod 0644`

Comment: "Directories should be executable or else you can't get listings of them." I don't think this is quite right: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Comment: Had `WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-sgx.list'` which was solved by changing this file's permissions to `0644`. All other files within the directory already had this permission level.

Answer (score 3):

1. You shouldn't use `sudo` to open graphical applications as root. You should install the gksu package from the Ubuntu Software Center and use the `gksudo` command instead of `sudo` to open a graphical application as root.
2. You shouldn't run software-properties-gtk as root either. If you need to be root, the application will prompt you in a popup window to authenticate with your user password. Since software-properties-gtk has a built-in authentication feature, you don't need to run it except as a regular user.
3. Try running software-properties-gtk properly, and see if you still get the same error.

---

#### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

gksu has been discontinued in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. To open software-properties-gtk as root run the following command:

```
sudo -H software-properties-gtk &>/dev/null
```

Comment: I learned something, but it did not solve my issue. Thank you anyway

Comment: bash: /dev/nulll: Permission denied
 for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Rocketq Thank you for bringing this to my attention. This `permission denied` error was caused by a typo error (misspelled the word `null`) which I found and corrected.

Comment: @karel `/etc/apt/sources.list` is neither an executable nor a directory. Why would you suggest adding execute permissions to it?

Answer (score 3):

The sources.list files are in /etc/apt/sources.list.d in newer version of Ubuntu. So you need to make a symbolic link from official-package-repositories.list to the old place to solve this problem:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

I think execution permission is needed, try to run the following command:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Comment: How is the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` connected to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` mentioned in the question?