# PATH and sources.list issue

Tags: apt, paths

I have discovered an issue with PATH and `/ect/apt/sources.list` Please could you advise how to resolve it?

As I am very novice to coding and stack exchange please could you comment and let me know which parts to edit out of this question.

I recently began looking into assembling genomes using [canu](https://github.com/marbl/canu)

Initially, I began using the full path to the command to utilize it i.e.
`~/Canu/canu/Linux-amd64/bin/canu`

I tried using the `-correct` option, however, had no success.
I surmised that it may be due to the directory containing the command file (also containing several other command files) would need to be added to PATH.

- Therefore, I added:

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:/localadmin/Canu/canu/Linux-amd64/bin/canu
  ```

  to the end of `~/.bashrc`
- Upon running:

  ```
  $ canu –help
  WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'`
  ```
- I looked into the original [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519154/how-to-solve-the-error-warningrootcould-not-open-file-etc-apt-sources-list) and followed the answers from here;

  1. `sudo ln -s /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list /etc/apt/sources.list`

     This gave no output and trying `canu –help` gave the same error as before.
  2. `sudo chmod -R 0644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

     This seemed to make things worse;

     ```
     localadmin@dna-ws:~$canu --help
     WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list
     WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list'
     WARNING:root:could not open file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mirror.oxfordnanoportal.com.list'
     WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-dell-service.list'
     WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
     WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-dell-matira-5-7.list'
     WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nanoporetech.sources.list'
     WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-dell.list'`
     ```

I took a look in `/ect/apt/` and found the following

```
localadmin@dna-ws:/etc/apt$ ls
apt.conf.d  preferences.d  sources.list~  sources.list.d  sources.list.save  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg~  trusted.gpg.d`
```

At this point, I thought I’d make a couple of backups before I break anything else, this displayed the contents of `sources.list.d` (I thought this may be useful context)

```
localadmin@dna-ws:/etc/apt$ cp -r sources.list.d ~/sources.list.d.backup
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/google-chrome.list': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/xenial-dell.list': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/mirror.oxfordnanoportal.com.list': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/nanoporetech.sources.list': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/mirror.oxfordnanoportal.com.list.save': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/xenial-dell-service.list.save': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/xenial-dell-matira-5-7.list.save': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/nanoporetech.sources.list.save': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/xenial-dell.list.save': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list.save': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/xenial-dell-matira-5-7.list': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'sources.list.d/xenial-dell-service.list': Permission denied`
```

I then managed to make a backup using `sudo`

EDIT: 
`localadmin@dna-ws:~$ type -a canu
-bash: type: canu: not found`

Comment: The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and the apt process in general have nothing to do with the functioning of Canu. You should undo the changes you have made according to the question you linked to, as they don't apply to your system (assuming it has a current Ubuntu version). I don't know why running `camu -help` would need to open the `sources.list.d` directory. Your `export` statement looks OK though.

Comment: The "full path" you mentioned actually is not a path per se. The `~` is expanded to your home folder in most shells, but you shouldn't rely on that, especially if you use it outside of a terminal. The path you appended to your `$PATH` variable is irritating (at least to me) because there is no `/localadmin/` folder on a stock Ubuntu system and creating folders in `/` is usually considered bad practice (except in some really advanced use cases).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `type -a canu`. You haven't actually added `canu` to your path based on the commands you show.

Comment: @jos, thanks so much for the help and advice I really appreciate it =D
To revert the changes I want to do
'unlink /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list' and `chmod` something `0644 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
Would that be enough (still working out the chmod options)

Comment: @danzel GOOD SPOT!!! It should be /home/localadmin/ I've corrected it in ~/.bashrc

Comment: You would use `sudo rm [linkname]` to remove just the link (not the file it links to). However, you have used `/etc/apt/sources.list` as the link name. That is, normally, a very vital file. Hopefully you have moved it or made a backup, otherwise your package management is messed up. I don't see how you could have created a link to a directory, while a file with the same name exists.

Comment: @terdon you're correct, I've added the edit as requested. Please could you elaborate as to what ive done wrong?

Comment: You need to give execute (opening) permission to the sources.list.d directory `sudo chmod 755 /etc/apt/sources.list.d` (**not** `-R` - don't want to make the contained files executable). You may be able to recover the main sources.list file from either the `sources.list.save` file or the `sources.list~` editor backup file. Presumable all the `WARNING:root:could not open` messages are because the shell's `command-not-found` mechanism is trying to search your sources for a package containing `canu` (since you messed up the `PATH` addition).

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks so much! 
As you've suggested I ran; `sudo chmod 755 /etc/apt/sources.list.d` then `sudo cp sources.list.save sources.list`
when I try `canu -help` I no longer get the warnings, but bash still cannot find the command, I thought the `~/.bashrc` file was correctly appended tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` variable is a list of *directories containing executables* and not of executables themselves. You attempted to add the `canu` executable to your PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/localadmin/Canu/canu/Linux-amd64/bin/canu
```

That makes your system look for a *directory* called `/localadmin/Canu/canu/Linux-amd64/bin/canu` in which it would then search for executables. Since there is no such directory (`canu` is a file), that command basically does nothing. What you wanted to do was:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/home/localadmin/Canu/canu/Linux-amd64/bin
```

(also note the quotes, those are important in case you have a directory with a space in its name)

Everything you did after that was not really relevant, I'm afraid. I don't understand the error you are getting, but since `canu` wasn't actually in your PATH, the `root:could not open file` error has nothing to do with `canu`. I suspect you messed up your PATH and that's causing various issues.

So, undo the changes you made to your `/etc/sources*` stuff following [the suggestions of @steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139371/path-and-sources-list-issue?noredirect=1#comment1888461_1139371), then remove the line you added to `.bashrc` and instead, add the right line I show above. Even better, don't add anything to `.bashrc` but use `~/.bash_profile` instead since that's a better place for defining global variables.

Then, log out and log back in and re-run `canu --help`. It should all work now.

Comment: thanks so much again, but unfortunately despite following the suggestions of @steeldriver and the ones you've suggested the outcome of entering `canu -help` is still `localadmin@dna-ws:~$ canu --help
No command 'canu' found, did you mean:
 Command 'cant' from package 'swap-cwm' (universe)
canu: command not found`

Comment: @GusBishop which file did you use? Although, at this point, it might be easier to debug this in chat. Give me a ping [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93051/room-for-terdon-and-gus) if you like.

Comment: Likely `/localadmin` should be `/home/localadmin` (this seems to be confirmed by the OP in comments)

Comment: @steeldriver oh, duh! I didn't even see the path. Thanks!

Comment: @GusBishop please see the updated answer. Try the new line.

Comment: still no success =( @steeldriver 
`bash_profile` looks like this now `export PATH="$PATH":/home/localadmin/Canu/canu/Linux-amd64/bin`

Comment: @steeldriver and terdon Thanks so much! All done now! You guys are ace! All good and sorted =D