# Installing anaconda3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, anaconda

These are my server details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I am trying to install conda using [anaconda installing on linux steps](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/)

I am facing no issues at this stage, But, when I finally call `conda list` to check if it is working properly, I get the following issue:

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

conda: command not found
```

I tried steps in ([How to solve the error: WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519154/how-to-solve-the-error-warningrootcould-not-open-file-etc-apt-sources-list)). It did not help in any way. It shows more errors:

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-xenial.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list'

conda: command not found
```

If I run `ls -la  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

the following question marks come :

```
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67.list.save': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67.list': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-xenial.list': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list.save': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list.save': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bazel.list
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bazel.list.save
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cuda-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67.list
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cuda-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67.list.save
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cuda.list
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cuda.list.save
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-xenial.list
```

I have also tried `rm -rf anaconda3` and reinstalling, that did not help either.

Hoping for a solution to the problem.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally ran `chmod` on your `/etc` directory at some point - the messages about `/etc/apt/sources.list` when you try to run `conda` are likely because of `command-not-found` working behind the scenes.